# How to see who the active user is without request Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a class based view and one of the functions is validating that the form has the correct selections. I need to reference the active user without using request as my function form_valid inherits only two parameters being: self and form. How could I make reference to the user who filled out the form in the form_valid function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just use user = self.request.user since the request is already a part of self. Spent a hour on that :/